# sorting in listview using asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

i want to do sorting in the listview from code behind, and i have done it by below code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
        BindLV("");
}

public DataTable GetEmployee(string query)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);
    DataTable dtEmp = new DataTable();
    ada.Fill(dtEmp);
    return dtEmp;
}

private void BindLV(string SortExpression)
{
    string UpdateQuery = "Select * from Employee" + SortExpression;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NorthwindConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    lvEmployee.DataSource = GetEmployee(UpdateQuery);
    lvEmployee.DataBind();
}

protected void lvEmployee_Sorting(object sender, ListViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    ImageButton imEmpID = lvEmployee.FindControl("imEmpID") as ImageButton;
    ImageButton imEmpName = lvEmployee.FindControl("imEmpName") as ImageButton;

    string DefaultSortIMG = "~/img/asc.png";
    string imgUrl = "~/img/desc.png";

    if (ViewState["SortExpression"] != null)
    {
        if (ViewState["SortExpression"].ToString() == e.SortExpression)
        {
            ViewState["SortExpression"] = null;
            imgUrl = DefaultSortIMG;
        }
        else
        {
            ViewState["SortExpression"] = e.SortExpression;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ViewState["SortExpression"] = e.SortExpression;
    }

    switch (e.SortExpression)
    {
        case "EmpID":
            if (imEmpName != null)
                imEmpName.ImageUrl = DefaultSortIMG;

            if (imEmpID != null)
                imEmpID.ImageUrl = imgUrl;

            break;

        case "EmpName":

            if (imEmpID != null)
                imEmpID.ImageUrl = DefaultSortIMG;

            if (imEmpName != null)
                imEmpName.ImageUrl = imgUrl;

            break;
    }
    BindLV(" order by " + e.SortExpression + " " + ((ViewState["SortExpression"] != null) ? "ASC" : "DESC"));
}
```

but the problem is i'm using another function for data paging as below in code behind which is contain of sorting as well:

```
 protected void DataPager1_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lvEmployee.DataSource = GetEmployee("Select * from Employee");
    lvEmployee.DataBind();

}
```

and my data pager code which is located at LayoutTemplate in .aspx page:

```
<asp:DataPager ID="DataPager1" runat="server" PagedControlID="lvEmployee" PageSize="5" onprerender="DataPager1_PreRender">
                <Fields>
                    <asp:NextPreviousPagerField ButtonType="Button" ShowFirstPageButton="true" ShowLastPageButton="true"/>
                </Fields>
            </asp:DataPager>
```

Every time i click at the name to sort it, there will be no change in the list.  E have traced the problem, and I have found out that the sorting function is working properly.  But before the page come up, the `DataPager1_PreRender` function is called and again shows the list without sorting.

Could you please guide me how to do sorting and dataPaging together without this problem.  Appreciate your consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have over come to this problem by using Session.
before i use session i found out every time i press the next page or anytime the page refresh it will execute the `DataPager1_PreRender()` and i have set the data source to

```
GetEmployee("Select * from Employee");
```

that's why the sorting never happens.
i have add `Session["UpdateQT"] = UpdateQuery;` to `BindLV()` to keep the update query and i have change the `DataPager1_PreRender()` to

```
string strtmp = Session["UpdateQT"].ToString();
    if (strtmp == null) 
    {
        strtmp = "Select * from Employee";
    }

    lvEmployee.DataSource = GetEmployee(strtmp);
    lvEmployee.DataBind();
```

to keep the latest query after sorting.
i hope it helps somebody.